# OpenMP with OpenCV on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, openmp

I'm having a problem getting OpenMP and OpenCV to play nicely with a new project in Xcode. The project in its current state does nothing but grab frames from the default camera and put them into a window. This functionality works. However, I would like to grab the frames in a separate thread, and I was hoping I could get some experience with OpenMP.

Merely checking the checkbox to enable OpenMP in Xcode wreaks havoc. The program, while it will compile, load and run just fine, will not respond to any events -- period. It just sits there, drawing grabbed frames. (I do get the OS X beachball, too, even though it's running fine.) I eventually have to force quit the app or kill it from Xcode. Keep in mind I get this behavior even *without* any OpenMP #pragmas -- I have only to enable the option in Xcode.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here. You might need to make sure that all OpenGL drawing commands are called from one thread.